# SWIFT: Communicating data from ViewController where tableView is defined to tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tvos, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I have programmatically implemented a tableView inside a viewController:

```
class MoviesViewController5: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    
    // There's a code responsible for populating this array
    var moviesItemsArray = [[movieItem]]()
    var sectionsData:[[String:Any]]?

    let cellIdentifier = "movieCardCell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
         tableView.register(sectionTableCell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableViewCell")
        displayTableView2()
    }

    func displayTableView2() {
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension MoviesViewController5: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
      return false
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? sectionTableCell2
          else {
                fatalError("Unable to create explore table view cell")}
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140
    }
}
```

The tableViewCell is also implemented programmatically:

```
class TableViewCell3: UITableViewCell {
    var moviesItems: [movieItem] = []
    let cellIdentifier = "movieCardCell"
    var collectionViewTest:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    fileprivate let cellOffset: CGFloat = 50
    
    func setupCollectionView() {
        collectionViewTest.delegate = self
        // TODO: Should I communicate moviesItems to TableViewCell3 or set the dataSource to MoviesViewController 5
        collectionViewTest.dataSource = self
    }
}

// Trying to display only one collectionView in tableCell
extension TableViewCell3: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return moviesItems.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
            cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! movieCardCell
        cell.movieImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: moviesItems[indexPath.item].imageURL))
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

**WHAT I WANT TO IMPLEMENT:**

1. Populate `moviesItemsArray` inside `MoviesViewController5`
2. Communicate each `moviesItems` of `moviesItemsArray` to each correspondant `TableViewCell3` based on the index
3. Affect the received movie data to the class property `moviesItems` of `TableViewCell3`
4. Display the movies data inside the `TableViewCell3` with the help of `collectionViewTest`

---

**PROBLEM (STEP 2): I don't know how to communicate each `moviesItems` of `moviesItemsArray` to each correspondant `TableViewCell3` based on the index.**
**NOTE:** *The other steps have already been taken care of.*

---

**QUESTION:** Should I communicate the data like any communication between different classes in SWIFT OR there's something that needs to be done with `collectionViewTest.dataSource` inside the `TableViewCell3`

Comment: Please ask only **one** question at a time. Start simple...  If you work through your problem so you can ask only the first question, you may find the answer yourself. At the least, you'll be able to post a single question that makes sense on its own.

Comment: The question is how can I communicate the information to tableViewCell. I just wanted to provide two approaches that I thought about (which was unnecessary, I could've just asked ONE question: How do I do this)

Answer (score 1):

> The question is how can I communicate the information to tableViewCell

That is what `cellForRowAt` is for. Your implementation is currently effectively empty:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? sectionTableCell2
    else {
        fatalError("Unable to create explore table view cell")
    }
    // HERE, THIS IS WHERE YOU DO IT
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer in a similar project:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let _cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CatalogueTableViewCell {
      // THIS
      _cell.images = images[indexPath.section]
      return _cell
    } else {
      return UITableViewCell()
    }
  }
```

Images is the property that's used for communicating:

```
class CatalogueTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  internal var images: [UIImage]! 
    }
```

Comment: Same as my answer.

Comment: @matt You did not provide details